# Java RMI Server does not print output

Tags: java, server, rmi

My RMI prime number program can't print the output in the Server class. The range of prime numbers is input in from the Client class.

PrimeNumber

```
 package example.primenumbers;

 import java.rmi.Remote;
 import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 public interface PrimeNumber extends Remote{

 public String sayPrimeNumber(int n) throws RemoteException;
  }
```

Server.java

```
package example.primenumbers;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements PrimeNumber{

public Server() {}

public String sayPrimeNumber(){

  int i =0;
  int n =0;
  int num =0;
  String  primeNumbers = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)         
  {                   
     int counter=0;           
     for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
     {
    if(i%num==0)
    {
    counter = counter + 1;
    }
 }
 if (counter ==2)
 {
    //Appended the Prime number to the String
    primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
 }

  }

      System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to n are :");
      System.out.println(primeNumbers);
  return primeNumbers;
    }



public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Server obj = new Server();
        PrimeNumber stub = (PrimeNumber) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.bind("PrimeNumber", stub);

      System.err.println("Server ready");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

Client

```
package example.primenumbers;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

private Client() {}

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i =0;
  int num =0;
  //Empty String
  String  primeNumbers = "";
  System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
  int n = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.close();
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)         
  {                   
     int counter=0;           
     for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
     {
    if(i%num==0)
    {
    counter = counter + 1;
    }
 }
 if (counter ==2)
 {
    //Appended the Prime number to the String
    primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
 }  
  } 

    String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        PrimeNumber stub = (PrimeNumber) registry.lookup("PrimeNumber");
        String response = stub.sayPrimeNumber();

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000000;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

I tried changing the println and return but still nothing happened. I hope someone could help me. Also, it's my first time doing RMI so please excuse my horrible knowledge in it.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it does.

Comment: Sorry, the indentation here is poor. Can you please show your client class? Where are you trying to read the printed output? The server console?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. I'm hoping it would output in the server.

Comment: Have you independently ran the prime numbers method outside of RMI? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. At first I did the prime numbers in a different class. Then I merged with the Client class and it worked. I tried with the Server class and it only printed "Prime numbers from 1 to n are :" and not the prime numbers.

Comment: The loop in the server code never runs, by the way. No values are being sent from the client to the server either

Comment: @cricket_007 I see. But if I don't put the loop in the server, the error says "cannot find symbol". I added the codes after the error and it ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code

- It always runs from 0, because n is not changed on the server side, so no factors are calculated, so all it outputs is `Prime numbers from 1 to n are :`
- The output is on the server side, rather than in the client program, so the client outputs nothing

The fix for the first is to send n as a parameter, the fix for the second is to send back the return value and print it from the client.

## Code for printing on both

### Client.java

```
package example.primenumbers;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        final int n;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
            n = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        final String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            final PrimeNumber stub = (PrimeNumber) registry.lookup("PrimeNumber");
            final String response = stub.sayPrimeNumber(n);

            System.out.println(response);
            final long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            final long duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000000;
            System.out.println("Took: " + duration);
        } catch (final RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### PrimeNumber.java

```
public interface PrimeNumber extends Remote {
    public String sayPrimeNumber(int n) throws RemoteException;
}
```

### Server.java

```
package example.primenumbers;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements PrimeNumber{

    public Server() {}

    public String sayPrimeNumber(final int n) throws RemoteException {

        String  primeNumbers = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int counter=0;
            for(int num = i; num>=1; num--)
            {
                if(i%num==0)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter ==2)
            {
                //Appended the Prime number to the String
                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to n are :");
        System.out.println(primeNumbers);
        return primeNumbers;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            final Server obj = new Server();
            final PrimeNumber stub = (PrimeNumber) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("PrimeNumber", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried not equalling to 0 but then an error said "variable n might not have been initialized". And It's actually a requirement in my project for server to display the prime numbers. If it was in the client then it would be fine.

Comment: In that case you want to print on both?

Comment: I see. So do I put the calculations in both Client and Server?

Comment: You can return the value like my example code does, so you don't repeat the calculation

Comment: Server.java:8: error: Server is not abstract and does not override abstract method sayPrimeNumber() in PrimeNumber
public class Server implements PrimeNumber{
       ^
Client.java:25: error: method sayPrimeNumber in interface PrimeNumber cannot be applied to given types;
            final String response = stub.sayPrimeNumber(n);
                                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors

Comment: I changed the interface [PrimeNumber.java], so you will need to change it to match the one in my answer

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't print the prime numbers in the Server. It does print in the Client.

Comment: can n be a final int, then you assign later in a try?

Comment: @AmeeJay I just tried it, and it is working fine for me, is there anything about your environment that may be breaking it?

Comment: @cricket_007 yep, it is only assigned once, unless an exception is thrown, which would leave the block, if it had a catch statement then it wouldn't be acceptable

Comment: @jrtapsell I don't think so? Does yours print in the Server?

Comment: @AmeeJay prints without issue my end

Comment: @jrtapsell my Prime Numbers class: package example.primenumbers;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface PrimeNumber extends Remote{

     public String sayPrimeNumber(int n) throws RemoteException;
} Does it effect it?

Comment: Can we move this to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156728/java-rmi-server-does-not-print-output)

Comment: Ah, the owner page had the text `Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room.`, seems it is wrong about that

Comment: @jrtapsell yeah. haha or maybe I really can't print in the server?

Comment: Are you trying to print in the registry?

Comment: @jrtapsell no. I think that would be harder. My project's assignment's reqs said "server program can display result collected from client"

Comment: If we can get someone else to run the code and see if it prints, I think it is an issue with your environment, it works on my machine

Comment: @jrtapsell environment as in machine? Can it effect the output?

Comment: @jrtapsell so my friend tried on her machine and it worked. Thank you so much! If I ever have a prob with Java I know you’re the person to look for 

Answer (score -1):

This loop in the server never runs

```
int i =0;
int n =0;
... 
for (i = 1; i <= n;  // here, i < 0 is never true
```

You need to pass `n` as a parameter to the method and send it from the client to the server rather than assign it to just 0

```
public String sayPrimeNumber(int n){
    int num =0;
    String  primeNumbers = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

And in the client

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
stub.sayPrimeNumber(n);
```

You also need to remove the prime calculations from the client and actually print the response variable

Comment: I tried not equalling to 0 but then an error said "variable n might not have been initialized"

Comment: You need to obviously assign a value, but you don't need to assign within that method.

Comment: When you said remove the calculations from client, do you mean just put in the Server?

Comment: Yes I do. You currently have it in both places

Comment: I see. But can the client still input the range of prime numbers?

Comment: The value of N? Yes